# Angular route without hash

Tags: angularjs, nginx, angular-ui-router

I have an app where the admin side is built in angular, but the front consumer facing side is not.. and lives on a different server.

**I'd like if visitors coming to:**

```
domain.com/#/admin => angular app
```

**But if they got to:**

```
domain.com
```

This goes to the other server

Is this possible?

Thanks.

---

**For a little more clarity, I think what I need is this:**

I have a rails app as an api that angular consumes. Rails lives on server A and Angular lives on server B.

Both servers use nginx as the web server.

Also, the rails app serves up its own content, so I want any path other than `admin` to go to rails.

What I want is if users go to:

mydomain.com --> they hit the rails app and content on server A

when they go to:

mydomain.com/admin or mydomain.com/#/admin --> they hit the angular app on server B

I think I almost figured it out with the following nginx configs on the rails server, server A:

```
upstream serverA {
  server rails;
  server unix:///var/www/rails/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock;
}

upstream serverB {
  server angular;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name serverA;
  root /var/www/rails/current/public;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://serverA;
  }

  location ~* ^/assets/ {
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header ETag "";
    break;
  }

  location /admin/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://serverB/#/;
  }
}
```

While this gets me close, my angular scripts and styles that are references by my angular index.html file are not being found.

Comment: What you want? Have domain.com in browser, but requests to another url? Or u just need simple redirect?

Comment: Angular uses `#` to handle routing, so if there is no Angular App in `domain.com`, you have to handle the `#` yourself. In this case, it's nothing but a bookmark.

Comment: you could easily redirect all request made to `domain.com` to `domain.com/#/admin` in apache config. No?